# How do I identify critical path in MS Project?

Tags: ms-project, critical-path

I'm using MS Project for my project management works. Would like to know how do I identify the critical path of the project and the dependencies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Standard Answer:
1. Check the "Critical Tasks" box in the Bar Styles group of the Format ribbon.  That will enable the red bars on the bar chart.
OR
2. Apply the built-in "Critical" filter in the Data group of the View ribbon.

In both cases, the Critical flag is assigned for tasks whose Total Slack is less than the threshold specified at the bottom of the Advanced Options dialog.

Comment: This answer works well as long as a) There is only a single critical path; b)There are no Deadlines and no SNLT/FNLT constraints; c) All tasks and resources use exactly the same Calendar; and d) There is no resource leveling applied.  Otherwise, Critical Tasks and the "Critical Path" are not the same. See here for explanations: https://wp.me/p6CCB4-fP

Answer (score 1):

The red line in the Gantt chart usually identifies the critical path.